# Let $X\subset \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, can $\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}X_i 2^{-i}$ converge to any number in $[0,1]$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $X\in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Can $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{i=1}X_i 2^{-i}$ converge to any number in $[0,1]$?
$X_i$ is the i-th coordinate of $X$

I would think not, for I do not see how the sum can be equal to an irrational number, or to a rational which can not be written with a power of 2 in the denominator...

Comment: Is it not just (one of the) the binary representation(s) of a number?

Comment: In your sum you use index i, but for the power of two you use variable n. And what is $X_i \cdot 2$? From your definition, $X$ is a set of functions from natural numbers to set containing $0$ and $1$, but it is not a function. So I do not understand that sum.

Comment: "I do not see how the sum can be equal to an irrational number" A finite sum of rationals has to be rational, but this is an infinite sum. We can for example write the irrational number $\pi$ as $\pi = 3 + \frac{1}{10^1} + \frac{4}{10^2} + \frac{1}{10^3} + \ldots$ which is an infinite sum of rationals (the $n$'th term corresponding to the $n$th decimal digit in base $10$) that is irrational.

Comment: @Arthur But what confuses me that he says X is a subset of the set of all functions. So X_i is a function, and what is a function times a number? That is confusing for me

Comment: Aah, I missed that. I would guess it's a typo, and he meant $\in$. I did that exact typo in my master's thesis, so I know it's possible.

Comment: @TStancek I've edited the question. I hope it's clearer now. Thanks

Comment: @Arthur I've edited the question. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. What about the subset? Shouldn't it be $\in$ ?

Comment: @Leo163 but the binary representation needs different weights in 0 to 9, here the weights are only 0 or 1.

Comment: @TStancek X is an infinite sequence of elements in {0,1}. You're right. I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be a number in $[0,1]$. You have to play this game to find you way to $a$ :

At the first step, check whether $a \geq \frac 12$. If yes, then $
\frac 12$ is included in the sum, otherwise it's not.

At the second step, check which side $a$ is, of $0.25$ or $0.75$ (wherever you get, to the right or left of $0.5$). If you're on the left side of the respective number , don't add $\frac 14$, otherwise add $\frac 14$ (in case of equality, we add the fraction).

I leave you to see what the $n$th step looks like. You will be somewhere, and will have to add or not add $\frac 1{2^n}$ depending upon whether your number is to the left or right of the current stop.

Also, convince yourself that, for example, playing this game with $a = \frac 13$ gives $\frac 13 = \frac{1}4 + \frac 1{16} + \frac 1{64} + ...$, so numbers with denominator not being a power of $2$, can also be expressed as such an infinite sum.

I also leave you to make this argument rigorous. The idea should be clear, though. If you are a programmer, this is very similar to binary search, a refined way of searching through a sorted list.

Comment: Thanks. By the way is there a specific way to write the preimage of this sum when applied to $\{r\}$ when $r \in [0,1]$?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. For every power of $0.5^k$ present in the sum, set corresponding coordinate k to 1, the rest set to zero.

Comment: @TStancek Thank you for your help. Also, I should mention that the binary search algorithm is a great motivation for this result. The next question you should ask is : Can we refine this result to powers of $3$ rather than $2$? How can we generalize this result?

Comment: To generalize the result, we would only need the series to sum to 1, or something more?

@TStancek I was thinking of a formula, that given $r$ we could reconstruct the sum, without having to go through the algorithm described in the answer...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. In what form the $r$ is given? In decimal form, by continous fraction, infinite sum? There is a step by step construction for decimal form, the others I do not know....

Comment: @TStancek ok. Thanks ;)